# XCUITest - Setting accessibilityFrame of button makes the button not hittable and not enabled

Tags: ios, automation, accessibility, uiaccessibility, xcuitest

Anyone see this before?  I'm setting the accessibilityFrame for a particular button.  Along with that, I'm making sure that it is an accessibilityElement.

When I debug, self.linkButton is totally unaccessible.  It is visible but it is not hittable and it isAccessibilityElement is equal to false.

If I remove the code setting the accessibilityFrame, all is well again and I can automate once again.

So this is telling me that there's something wrong when I set the accessibilityFrame.  Am I missing something?

```
let howWorksAccessibilityFrame = CGRect(x: self.linkButton.frame.origin.x * 2, y: self.linkButton.frame.origin.y + (self.linkButton.frame.height * -3), width: self.linkButton.frame.width * 3, height: self.linkButton.frame.height * 3)

self.linkButton.accessibilityFrame = howWorksAccessibilityFrame
self.linkButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
```